# Reproduce particle system settings in geometry nodes

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes, normals

I have a tree generated with m-tree add on, which is based on a particle system. I would like to use it as an instance in another particle system. As far as I understand, such nested particle system is only supported via geometry nodes. I would like to port my particle system settings to geometry nodes.

I have a problem with Rotation > "normal" orientation. It looks like this:
[image: desired orientation]

According to [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/rotation.html) it orients the particles "to emitter’s surface normal, the objects Y axis points outwards."

I tried to reproduce this setting in the geometry nodes trying different settings:
[image: geometry nodes]

but I failed to find a setting which would match the particle system one. How can I reproduce the particle system setting in geometry nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce the original rotation with this setting. Not sure why it's so complicated.

[image: solution]

Comment: "normally" you only have to plug the rotation to the "align euler to vector" vector input and that to the rotation. so ...just one node instead of your 3 needed.

Comment: @Chris would you be able to show how you do that? It seems that particle system uses a different set of default axis (trying to make Y to match normal, as opposed to Z), which is super confusing to duplicate. The above worked for one model I used, but when I turned it around, the particle system returned in a different way from the geometry nodes ones...

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3gbV.jpg

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I got a different rotation of the particles (which couldn't be fixed through transform)

Comment: After a more careful looking, it seems like a bug in the particle system. I guess I'll live with the geometry nodes version, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome